# How to skip serialization in impl of `serde::ser::Serialize`?

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to skip serialization entirely based on some value in a custom implementation of `Serialize`

```rust
impl Serialize for MyType {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match &self.value {
            Action::Serialize => //serialize.serialize_struct(  etc...
            Action::NoSerialize => Ok(()) // <= Error. How do I return Ok and skip serialization ? 
       }
    }
}
```

The error message reads

```
mismatched types
expected associated type `<S as mystuff::_::_serde::Serializer>::Ok`
         found unit type `()`rustcE0308
mod.rs(160, 22): consider constraining the associated type `<S as mystuff::_::_serde::Serializer>::Ok` to `()`: `<Ok = ()>`
```

but I have no idea on how to specify the suggested constraint `<Ok = ()>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to depend a bit on the serializer. Some serializers (e.g. Bincode) will skip over unit values, so you can just use `Serializer::serialize_unit()`. However others, like `serde_json`, will give a value for unit, e.g. `null`.

The problem is that, in some contexts, serializers *need* a value. For example, if you are serializing to a Json map (object literal), it doesn't makes sense to have a key without a value, but you will have already serialized the key before you even examine the value.

So to skip values generically, you need to customise the serialization of the struct or collection that contains the value, to determine the right thing to do. In some cases, this might mean writing custom serialization for the "parent" type, to make it aware of the thing that needs to be skipped. Other times, you can use `serde` attributes to customise it:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Parent {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "MyType::no_serialize")]
    pub my_value: MyType,
}

impl MyType {
    fn no_serialize(&self) -> bool {
        matches!(self, Action::NoSerialize)
    }
}
```

> but I have no idea on how to specify the suggested constraint `<Ok = ()`>

The suggestion is a red herring in this case. `Ok` here is an associated type of the `Serializer` that you are using. It's not something you can change, and changing it to `()` would mean creating a serialization format that would be empty for *all* values.

Comment: Thanks. Since I could not change the parent, I went for a different strategy (and a myriad of annotations....)